# Error in creation of work-item in Azure DevOps using Pytest/Python

Tags: python, exception, azure-devops, pytest, workitem

I am trying to create a work-item using Python and `requests` library.

```
def test_create_work_item(work_items):
    payload = {
                'op': 'add',
                'path': '/fields/System.Title',
                'value': 'Sample bug'
            }
    pl = json.dumps(payload)
    work_item = work_items.create(body=pl, type='bug')
    assert work_item.status_code == 200
```

I am getting the below error for this :

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"You must pass a valid patch document in the body of the request.","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssPropertyValidationException,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common","typeKey":"VssPropertyValidationException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
```

The same body works okay with Postman. So not sure what more is needed here to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I`m not familiar with Python.... Check this example: [Create work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#create-work-item)

The API uses an array of new fields:

```
[   
    {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample task"
    } 
]
```

In your case, you use just one field in the request:

```
{
    'op': 'add',
    'path': '/fields/System.Title',
    'value': 'Sample bug'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have been following the official documentation. The same payload works on Postman and not with Pytest is what has raised this question.

Comment: Got it. It needed the square brackets.